# SPClientPeoplePicker is not defined in custom edit form

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-form, clientpeoplepicker

I am getting the error "**SPClientPeoplePicker is not defined in custom edit form"**. But it is working properly in default edit/new item form. (Sharepoint Online)

Getting the below error when trying to use it in custom edit form.

[image]

I need to use **SPClientPeoplePicker** to manage the people picker values in the custom form. Please help.

**-- EDIT --**

I've added the ***clientpeoplepicker.js*** file in to the default edit form.But still not able to get the people picker fields object (added screenshot below).
I think people picker fields in custom edit forms are different than one in the default edit form.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you have to request the script on demand, try this in your code:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('clientpeoplepicker.js', 'SPClientPeoplePicker', function () {
    //awesome code in here
});
```

Comment: Sorry. It is not working in custom edit form. Still getting the same error. What I want to achieve is to automatically fill people picker fields, and I am able to do it in the default edit form. But not able to do it in custom edit form.

Comment: Can you post the whole script?